# How to disable core dump in a docker image?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a service that uses an Docker image. About a half dozen people use it. However, occasionally containers produces big core.xxxx dump files. How do I disable it on docker images? My base image is Debian 9.

Answer (score 1):

To disable core dumps set a `ulimit` value in /etc/security/limits.conf file and defines some shell specific restrictions.

A hard limit is something that never can be overridden, while a soft limit might only be applicable for specific users. If you would like to ensure that no process can create a core dump, you can set them both to zero. Although it may look like a boolean (0 = False, 1 = True), it actually indicates the allowed size.

- soft core 0
- hard core 0

The asterisk sign means it applies to all users. The second column states if we want to use a hard or soft limit, followed by the columns stating the setting and the value.

Comment: I have tried this, but dump files can still be created. :(

Comment: You have to start your container with the option --ulimit core=0 to disable coredumps.  refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704192/how-to-disable-core-file-dumps-in-docker-