# How to disable core dumps in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, coredump

I have a Lambda function that runs from a custom Docker image. The image includes a Chromium instance (via [@sparticuz/chromium](https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium)). The Lambda function runs puppeteer with this Chromium instance. Occasionally, the Chromium instance crashes, and every time this happens, a core dump file is generated (e.g. `/tmp/core.chromium.359`). The problem with these files is that they can occupy a lot of space (several gigabytes), which will make the Lambda run out of free disk space and start failing. To avoid this, I delete the dump files on exit, but disabling them altogether would be a cleaner solution. Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704192/how-to-disable-core-file-dumps-in-docker-container), disabling core dumps in Docker is only possible from outside the container, so running something like `ulimit -c 0` won't work in the Lambda function either.