# Disable Core File Dumps on Docker Image/Container Hosted on AWS ECS/Fargate

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition, core-file

My docker container runs a python app (backend API) that allows users upload various documents, PDF's mostly. so i think due to the pdf/file(s) upload, the container keeps creating core dump files: shown below
[screenshot_coredump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO4Yq.png)

This slows down the container an eventually the container would crash!
I have used a similar question asked on stack overflow ([how-to-disable-core-file-dumps-in-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704192/how-to-disable-core-file-dumps-in-docker-container))but the solution seems to work on docker run on a local pc. how can i fix this on a production environment.

container runs ubuntu:22.04

i use a dockerfile:

below is my docker file config:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Download the pandoc deb file
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/3.1.2/pandoc-3.1.2-1-amd64.deb

# Install the downloaded deb file
RUN dpkg -i pandoc-3.1.2-1-amd64.deb

COPY . .

CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "17", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--timeout", "120", "main:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80"]
```

i also use a task definition to deploy my container:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:$ARN:task-definition/a$task-def:30",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "$NAME",
            "image": "$ARN.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE-NAME:22636912fe7ab73cf3bd23bdb3d88d317d00b272",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "$CONTAINER_NAME-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [
                {
                    "value": "arn:aws:s3:::$S3_Resource",
                    "type": "s3"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/$LOG_Group",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "$LOG_FAMILY",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::$ARN:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::$ARN:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 30,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "new",
            "host": {}
        }
    ],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.env-files.s3"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.increased-task-cpu-limit"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.extensible-ephemeral-storage"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "8192",
    "memory": "24576",
    "ephemeralStorage": {
        "sizeInGiB": 200
    },
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2023-07-30T20:49:22.769Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:sts::$ARN:assumed-role/github/github",
    "tags": []
}
```

github actions script:

```
name: Deploy Document-Management-service To Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

env:
  AWS_REGION:                  # set this to preferred AWS region, e.g. us-west-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY:      # set this to your Amazon ECR repository name
  ECS_SERVICE:         # set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER:         # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: .github/workflows/main-task-definition.json      # set this to the path to your Amazon ECS task definition                                           # file, e.g. .aws/task-definition.json
  CONTAINER_NAME:            # set this to the name of the container in the
                                               # containerDefinitions section of your task definition

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read # This is required for actions/checkout@v2

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ARN }} #AWS ARN With IAM Role
        role-session-name: github
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, Push, Tag and Deploy Container to ECR.
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG --ulimit core=0 .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
        container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

i tried adding:
`--ulimit core=0`
to my github action script it looked like this
`docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG --ulimit core=0 .`

but apparently I realized it was said to be used with a `docker run` command

so is there any way to disable core file dump on a production environment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable core dumps in Linux by setting `ulimit core` hard and soft values to `0`.

This can be done via the `ulimit` setting in [the ECS container definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html).

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I need a bit clarity on what option I am to use for the ulimits... is it `core`,  `data` or `fsize` ?

Comment: I said `ulimit core` in my answer. It's `core`.

Comment: alright, i'll try that and give my feed back